# reload while switching pages (symfony 3)

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

I am working on a Symfony app, my problem consists on moving from the script to the form without refreshing the pages

[image]

I used ajax to stop reload the main layout which contains the two parts (script and form) and I don't know exactly how to maintain the form inputs when moving to the script part

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include your relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you. Before posting a question, it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

use preventDefault(); to prevent default behavior evenement (click button for example) but i don't understand the role of script button and what changes make to interface?

Comment: the script button takes to another page , i"ve tried the preventDefault() before and it didn't work for me, all i want is to not delete what's already written in the form when switching to the script page

Comment: put your script to know and use session storage to maintain input values to another page